# Is there a way to visualize records stored in an iPhone app via Core Data?

Tags: xcode, core-data

I have an app which, for good reasons, can only be debugged on a device. I'm using Core Data for the first time, and I'd like to be able to easily inspect the records that are stored by the app on the device.

I imagine that Core Data is by default backed by SQLite on the iPhone, so this question might be as simple as asking: "What's the easiest way to extract the SQLite database for an app installed by Xcode without jailbreaking it?"

Any experience someone could lend regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Core Data Editor](http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor/). Just get the sqlite store from the device and use it with CDE. Costs 20 bucks but I think it is worth it.